# Azure, Log4Net log file, FTP transfer, Response: 550

Tags: ftp, log-files, azure

I have an ASP.NET MVC website on Azure using log4net file appender. 
I cannot download the log files with FileZilla because of the following error:

> Response: 550 The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. 
>   Error:  Critical file transfer error

Is there a setting on log or Azure that I can use the be able to download log files while the web application is running? I do not want to shut down web app or IIS because of that.

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting the locking method on the Appender to either one of the following:

```
<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
```

or

```
<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+InterProcessLock" />
```

Alternatively you could switch to using the [RollingFileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html) and then only download log files that aren't currently being written to.  This Appender can rotate files based on date/time or file size and can limit the number of files it creates to avoid running out of local storage space.

Comment: Hi Simon. Thank you for the answer. I am using the RollingFileAppender. But I would like to read (download) the files currently being written to. That's my problem. If you are saying that this is not possible I will need to look into SQL appender or some other option to see the log files "live".

Comment: I blogged about using TraceAppender with Azure Diagnotics last year.  This writes to a Storage Table which you could read back as required.  http://blog.kloud.com.au/2014/10/22/logging-with-log4net-and-azure-diagnostics-on-web-and-worker-roles/